# Gradle task should run before dependencies

Tags: gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, gradlew

I created 2 tasks:
Task A for downloading a file with conf from remote
Task B read the file and add it as an external variable

```
ext.versions = [
            kotlin: '1.1.1'
]
```

And then dependencies should run with

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$versions.kotlin'
}
```

I got an error:

```
> Could not find org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:[].
```

How can I start tasks A and B before `Configuration` and `compile` phases?

Comment: You can't run tasks before configuration

Comment: @tim_yates how? It's will be enough to update the dependency version?